# can you put views field values into a global token?

Tags: 8, tokens, meta-tags

Suppose I want to use a paragraph field value of an entity for metatag title (by using [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) views module)

I can successfully get the value of the paragraph entity and display it on the view

[image]

Now, is there a way i can save those field to a token so i can use it here?
[image]

[image]

Regards,

Comment: anything is possible..if you can write code :)

Comment: @IvanJaros I can actually code :) Do you know where should I start?

Comment: `Do you know where should I start?` start by creating a token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible if paragraphs module does not provide this token itself. The way to do it would be to create your own token. Even with this it may be tricky to figure out that information.

To create your own token you will need to look into the hook_token_* items such as [hook_token_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7.x).

It sounds like to me your best bet would be attempting to hook into the views pre processing and change the value that way.

Comment: Yup, i solved the problem by creating a custom token. Thanks to all!